# How to protect Azure Service Principal in your PowerShell Code

Tags: powershell, azure, service-principal

Let's say I have my PowerShell code which takes specific actions on my Azure subscription. I understood it has to log into Azure using my Azure username or maybe an Azure Service Principal.

In my case I would like to use a Service Principal because a lot of people are going to use this code and I don't want to give everyone access into my subscription. So I provide access only to this SP.

I realized, to log in using a SP, I need to include the App ID and the Key in my code and if my code is compromised then someone from outside our company could also use the App ID and the Key to log in and do stuff on my subscription.

Is there any way I could protect myself against such security risk? I see there is also a section on Azure AD which I can specify users/groups who can access the Service Principal (Azure App). But will it be more like a double authentication? can you please point me in the right direction?

If you could also share with me some sample code it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Setup the service principal to login via certificate, and distribute the certificate with the script, and have it authenticate that way. Then if somebody external gets their hands on your script they can't use it to affect your subscription without also having the certificate.

Comment: The use of certificate also doesn't eliminate the risk

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I agree with TheMadtechnician. You create a service principal with certificate and give the certificate to the people you trusted. Use service principal+certificate to login your subscription. `$Certs = Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My\ | Where-Object {$_.Subject -match $CertificateName };Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint $Cert.Thumbprint -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalApplicationId -TenantId $TenantId`

Comment: If you could use certificate to login your Azure subscription, I could share full code to you. When your certificate leaks, you could disable the app. I think it is more safer than password.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, please don't do it this way.  Anyone who gains access to the certificate (if you are distributing it with your code) will also have access as the service principal to Azure.

I'd suggest you create an Azure Automation runbook and attach a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) to it.  You could then create a small html file that would execute the runbook (prompting for any parameters that you require).  This way, the users can only run the code that you setup (via webhook) and you can cycle the webhook url (by deleting it and recreating a new one) periodically.

Comment: The problem is that the action the code executes is too dangerous and that means if someone gets access to the web page they have the possibility to execute it and that should be avoided. I was hoping for an additional authentication layer before they execute the code through the SP...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#security  TLDR: You can add a pre-shardkey or other validation form in the message body and write logic to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess everything has its own risks... just want to reduce it as much as possible... any idea what's the access list in the Azure AD Application (SP) ? Could be related to this scenario?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are referring to, link?